# Try, except and retry with new condition when failing

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write an algorithm which sums up all the values being to the left and right of the maximum value of an array (including the maximum). The summation should stop when a condition is met. For example:

```
import numpy as np


data = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, -1]

summ1 = 0
summ2 = 0
j = 1
k = 0
n = 0

for i in range(len(data)):

    if data[i] == np.amax(data):

        while data[i + j] > 1:
            summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
            j += 1

        while data[i - k] > 1:
            summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
            k += 1
        
total = summ1 + summ2
```

This works fine. But depending on the condition this can  raise an `IndexError`. For example:

```
import numpy as np


data = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, -1]

summ1 = 0
summ2 = 0
j = 1
k = 0
n = 0

for i in range(len(data)):

    if data[i] == np.amax(data):

        while data[i + j] > -2:
            summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
            j += 1

        while data[i - k] > 1:
            summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
            k += 1
        
total = summ1 + summ2
```

Now I am trying to figure out a way to manipulate the condition in a loop until it can enter the while loop. I have thought of something like this:

```
data = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, -1]

summ1 = 0
summ2 = 0
j = 1
k = 0
n = 0

while True:
    try:

        for i in range(len(data)):

            if data[i] == np.amax(data):

                while data[i + j] > -2 + n:
                    summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
                    j += 1


                while data[i - k] > 3:
                    summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
                    k += 1
        

        total = summ1 + summ2 
        break

    except IndexError:
        n = n + 1
```

But this does not work and I can`t figure out why. The idea is to increment `n`, when an `IndexError` is raised, re-enter the `try`-statement and check if the `while` condition can be met (in this example if `while data[i + j] > -1:` , so `n == 3`) and finally breaking out of the while-loop. But it just keeps incrementing my `n` and the `while` condition is never met. It is a very artificial example but I need to know why this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that when you increment `j`, you eventually reach the end of the array (since all values are greater than -2). This triggers an `IndexError` (in the case of the sample data you gave, the index you end up searching for is 13, but there are only 13 items in the list so of course that won't work).

The reason incrementing `n` does not work in your code is that you never reset `j`. So you take `n` up by one but when you re-enter the forloop, `j` is already 8 so once you get to `i = 5` there is an `IndexError` again which sends you to the except statement, increments `n` and restarts the process.

I'm not sure why you would want to use this code with incrementing `n` in the first place. If you want to find the sum of the elements matching your condition just add a simple check inside a while loop which prevents the index error like so:

```py
import numpy as np


data = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, -1]

summ1 = 0
summ2 = 0
j = 1
k = 0
n = 0

for i in range(len(data)):

    if data[i] == np.amax(data):

        while i + j < len(data):
            if data[i + j] > -2:
                summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
                j += 1
            else:
                break    

        while i - k >= 0:
            if data[i - k] > 1:
                summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
                k += 1
            else:
                break  

total = summ1 + summ2
```

This way if `i + j >= len(data)` (which is what would otherwise trigger the index error), the list is not even indexed. Also you should do it with the `i - k` part too. Otherwise if you get to negative indices, it won't give you an index error but it will start adding items from the end of the list.

If you want to do it with incrementing `n` (which I personally find to be a strange solution), you can. Just put `j = 1` inside the outer while loop:

```py
data = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, -1]

n = 0

while True:
    
    summ1 = 0
    summ2 = 0
    j = 1
    k = 0
    
    try:

        for i in range(len(data)):

            if data[i] == np.amax(data):

                while data[i + j] > -2 + n:
                    summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
                    j += 1


                while data[i - k] > 3:
                    summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
                    k += 1


        total = summ1 + summ2
        break

    except IndexError:
        n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current code, `j` never gets reset to zero, the first while loop will keep throwing an index error.

I'm not clear on what this logic is intended to accomplish, but resetting `j` and `k` seems to solve the index issue.

Try this code:

```
import numpy as np

data = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, -1]

summ1 = 0
summ2 = 0
j = 1
k = 0
n = 0

print (np.amax(data))  # 5

while True:
    print('w > ', n)
    try:

        for i in range(len(data)):

            if data[i] == np.amax(data):

                while data[i + j] > -2 + n:
                    print('w1', i, j)
                    summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
                    j += 1

                while data[i - k] > 3:
                    print('w2', i, k)
                    summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
                    k += 1
        
        total = summ1 + summ2 
        break

    except IndexError:
        n = n + 1
        j = k = 0
        print('ex',n)        

print('total',total)
```

Output

```
5
w >  0
w1 5 1
w1 5 2
w1 5 3
w1 5 4
w1 5 5
w1 5 6
w1 5 7
ex 1
w >  1
w1 5 0
w1 5 1
w1 5 2
w1 5 3
w1 5 4
w1 5 5
w1 5 6
w2 5 0
w2 5 1
total 45
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when the exception occurs, the values of j and k are not reset and thus the exception keeps on reoccuring.

Check for index limits in while conditions:

```
    while i+j < len(data) and data[i + j] > -2 + n:
        summ1 = summ1 + data[i + j]
                j += 1


    while i-k > 0 and data[i - k] > 3:
        summ2 = summ2 + data[i - k]
        k += 1
```

This solution does not require exception handling